# How to make background image resize to hold all text inside it

Tags: html, css

How to make all the text goes inside the background image on all screen sizes, I've wrote this code but the text still goes outside the image . Also there is a white space on the right side on large screens , how to remove it .

Screen shots :

**Extra white space on the right side screen shot**

[image: extra white space on the right side screen shot]

**Text goes outside the background on small screens**

[image: text goes outside the background on small screens]

HTML :

```
 <div class="h-100">
    <div class="h-100" id="background">
      <div class="container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo suscipit quis sed temporibus eius magni, adipisci, ad, maxime saepe mollitia id sunt perspiciatis asperiores earum voluptate fugiat pariatur. Officia repudiandae iusto maxime ad quibusdam! Esse adipisci eos tenetur rerum amet, doloremque quidem commodi architecto quis, quaerat culpa, distinctio praesentium sunt.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS :

```
#background {
  background-image: url("../imgs/15409-[Converted].jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: what about making a `div` that fills the whole page, then contain your text to that div? What do you want to do when there's more text than what would be able to fit within the image?

Comment: I want to make the font smaller or let the image grow bigger, whatever possible I don't mind

Comment: But my main thing is to remove the extra white space on the write side

Comment: Set background-size to 100% >> `background-size: 100%;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you may want `background-size: cover;`. This will scale the image proportionally so that the background is fully covered, possibly cropping it.

If you want to prevent cropping you can set `background-size: 100%;` for an image that will cover the whole background but may be stretched.

([details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size))

Comment: but  ```background-cover``` cut the image on the small screens !!

Comment: I want the same exact image on all screens

Comment: not possible, you will either have to warp the image by stretching it or accept that it will be cropped. Not every viewport is the same shape, so the image will either be cut or warped to fill the screen

Answer (score 0):

I read your comments to other answers and I think you misunderstand what is happening here with image aspect ratios.

IF however, you do want to totally stretch and warp the image to fill the screen each time and not repeat.. then use `background-size: 100%;` in your CSS for the background image.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the answers, I think that what you are looking for is changing `background-size: contain;` for `background-size: 100% 100%;`, thus stretching the image to always fulfill the content.

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

You can test my idea on https://jsfiddle.net/alemohamad/fu8szLmc/3/.